# Kineticjs mouse on & out canvas or stage

Tags: kineticjs

I will like detect when the mouse enter on canvas and when go outside in kineticjs.In this moment I have this solution.

```
var _mouse_uno='mouseenter mousemove';
var _mouse_dos='mouseout';

stage.on(_mouse_uno, function(evt) {  //QUE NO SE SALGA LA IMAGEN
    layer_icos.hide();
});

stage.on(_mouse_dos, function(evt) { 
    layer_icos.show();
});
```

But when I enter in another layer, they show me the layer `layer_icos` that I not like.

Also it is possible that animate all the layer with a translation, to go outside.

Thank you and sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QxL7h/

The stage will fire mouse events like mouseenter/mouseleave only when the mouse is over a shape.

The stage will not fire mouse events when the mouse is over an empty part of the stage.

So if you always want to get mouse events on the stage you can add a nearly transparent rectangle that fills the stage.

This way the mouse is always over a shape an will always fire mouse events

```
var bk=new Kinetic.Rect({
    x:0,
    y:0,
    width:stage.getWidth(),
    height:stage.getHeight(),
    fill:"white",opacity:0.01
});
layer.add(bk);
layer.draw();
```

Comment: Thank you, I check it. But if I realease this, if the childrens that have mouse events, this mouse event no execute, I check it the same layer, with diferent layers, with and without evt.cancelBubble

Comment: If you have two layers, one with the objects that have mouseenter and mouseout , also have another bigger object opacity 0.01 with  mouseenter mouseout. For me not work the propagation.If you have the bigger up the objects layer not execute, and if you have the objects layers up, when enter in the objects execute mouseout in the bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I have temporarily solved with the position.

```
 bk.on('mouseenter', function(evt) { 

for (var j=0;j<iconos_bases.length;j++){
        //iconos_bases[j].group.setVisible(false);
        iconos_bases[j].group.tween.play()
        continue;
    }
stage.draw();
});
bk.on('mouseout', function(evt) { 
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    console.log(pos);   
    if ( (pos.x <=0) || (pos.y <=0) ){
         for (var j=0;j<iconos_bases.length;j++){
        //iconos_bases[j].group.setVisible(true);
        iconos_bases[j].group.tween.reverse()
     }
    stage.draw();
   }

});
```

I not resolved:

If you have two objects with mouse enter and mouseout, that are overlaping (one above the other), when enter in one go outside another, and the propagation are not working for me.

I solved with :

```
var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
if ( (pos.x <=0) || (pos.y <=0) ){}
```